# How to call a function from secret.yml file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way to call a method from secrets.yml file in rails?

```
production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
  encrypt_key: <%= ENV['ENCRYPT_KEY'] || missing_key('encrypt_key') %>
```

Where can we define the missing key? The helper files are not loaded yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initializers! Define your method in an initializer file (`config/initializers/your_file.rb`).

```
# config/initializers/your_file.rb

def missing_key(name)
   # get a missing key by name
end
```